# Как создать тему с градиентом для TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-themes

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста, как создать тему с градиентом для TextInputLayout как на рисунке. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой градиент можно сделать несколько проще, чем в другом ответе:

**res/drawable/gradient.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:centerColor="#888888"
        android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:startColor="#FFFFFF" />

</shape>
```

**layout.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Телефон"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"/>
</LinearLayout>
```